# Google Apps Marketplace API customerLicense with OAuth2

Tags: google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, google-apps-marketplace

We are migrating our **Google Apps Marketplace Apps** to OAuth2 authentication.

We have figured out some of difference in migration process such as replace **OAuth1 two-legged authentication** with **Service Account OAuth2 strategy** to impersonate domain and perform some background task.

In our current OAuth1 apps we have some queries to **customerLicense** service to check if some domain removed our App from Marketplace.

I have seen this is not possible to do with OAuth2 by the moment. Is there any Service with Service Account OAuth2 that replace this mechanism to check customerLicense for a specific Application?

Since I am using only service account keys I have not found documentation about how to consume this API with these type of credentials. In fact documentation says only Oaurh two legged keys are able to consume this API.

Can you send me some link where I can read about consuming this API with service account Keys?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [same API](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/) with OAuth2. If there are any issues please let us know.

Comment: Since I am using only service account keys I have not found documentation about how to consume this API with these type of credentials. In fact documentation says only Oaurh two legged keys are able to consume this API.

Can you send me some link where I can read about consuming this API with service account Keys?

Comment: I figured out how to implement. See my other post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410538/error-consuming-customerlicense-app-marketplace-with-service-account-oauth2. I have made a License API Client Java implementation based on google-api-client 1.17 which nobody have done before. Where can I share it?