# How to use Google Apps Marketplace LicenseNotification API

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to use LicenseNotification API from the [test page here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/licenseNotification/list#try-it) for a test app I have built, published and already installed in one of our test domains.

App status on the CWS is published (published, GAM: published) and the app works fine.

I am logged in using the app project owner and I enabled OAuth 2.0 Authorization switch. Set the applicationId (which one is right, the one from Developers Console Marketplace SDK configuration or the one from CWS aka element id? I tried both..), clicked on Execute and I get the following response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID"
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My app is published but visibility is set to "private" for my test domain only.

Comment: I think you have to make the call to the api using service account, check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410538/error-consuming-customerlicense-app-marketplace-with-service-account-oauth2

Comment: You're right but I was just performing a quick & dirty test from the doc page "Try it now". I think this one should work for a published app.